# Android - Can I scan and distinguish Wifis that have same SSID but different BSSIDs?

Tags: android, wifi

Can I scan and distinguish Wifis that have same SSID but different BSSIDs? I want to obtain all of BSSIDs by APs that have same SSID.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes we can definitely scan and distinguish Wifis based on there BSSIDs.

Try this:

```
class WifiScanReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @SuppressLint("UseValueOf")
        public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {

            List<ScanResult> wifiScanList = wifiManager.getScanResults();

            for (int i = 0; i < wifiScanList.size(); i++) {
                String ssid = wifiScanList.get(i).SSID; //Get the SSID
                String bssid =  wifiScanList.get(i).BSSID //Get the BSSID
                 /****
                //manipulate bssid or ssid according to your need
                //in your case, use it for differentiating
                ***/

            }
        }
    }
```